# Performance tuning for Flask, Gevent, SQLAlchemy+Postgresql

Tags: python, node.js, postgresql, flask, gevent

We have been considering building a large API stack on Flask+Gevent with Postgresql DB.

However, we have been getting a lot of internal interest for using node.js because of articles like [this](http://www.jayway.com/2015/04/13/600k-concurrent-websocket-connections-on-aws-using-node-js/) 
We have not been able to find ways to write async api code and performance tune Flask+Gevent setups.

I'm wondering has anybody done any tuning of high performance Flask+Gevent API and is willing to post configs here.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on where you expect the bottle necks to be? I think this comes down to what language are you most comfortable with.

Comment: Are you planning on hosting a large number of mostly idle connections (as the linked article is benchmarking) or is this API going to have a lot of throughput (reads, writes, both)?

Comment: @JoeDoherty - I want it to be Python.. but I'm not seeing any canonical way to build APIs in Python/Gevent that works for performance. Since I cant find any resources (as opposed to Node with all this documentation and performance tuning knobs - e.g. the GC).

Comment: @SeanVieira that's an interesting question - our API has a mix of both: mostly throughput APIs and some idle connections. BUT, I wouldnt mind moving them all to a idle websocket based system if there is a way to do it with decent performance. FYI  - on the client side, we use a lot of Python and Android/Java.

Comment: If your not using web sockets then it doesn't really matter. For web sockets I probably would take a look at node.